# How to create a new instance of a object type

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a base class where I inherit my forms.

This base class has a property:

```
public object ParentObj{get; set; }
```

Now, inside one form I need to create an instance of this referenced object:

What I have right now is this:

```
var type = this.ParentObj.GetType();
object instance = (typeof(type))Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

But I can't compile. I'm doing something wrong.

Any clue?

Comment: Can't compile? So that means you're getting a compilation error? Probably a good idea to share the error with us.

Comment: You got a good answer, but next time, please provide error messages or the like. "I can not compile" is not considered a proper problem description.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the use case here is. It seems like it might reflect a poor design choice somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to cast it as anything; `object` is fine:

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

You cannot perform a cast to a type known only as a variable, unless you switch to a generic method (and cast to `T`) - but: you don't need to.